# Update image src with input field.?

Tags: php, html

Three url input fields.

```
<input type="url" name="image1"/>

<input type="url" name="image2"/>

<input type="url" name="image3"/>
```

And three images tag.

```
<img src="Image link from first input"/>

<img src="Image link from second input"/>

<img src="Image link from third input"/>
```

Can i do that with php.?and use some condition for example if i want only change one image src than other src code not change i mean just update only one image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simple way:

```
<img src="Image link from first input"/>
```

becomes

```
<img src="<php echo $_GET['image1']]?>"/>
```

assumes your form uses get

Comment: Thanks for quick response.yes it's working.I have one more question can i ask.

Comment: Actually i want to make admin panel i have three image on my main page this will show latest images.i want update images use this method as you describe.but now i have facing problem when i set only one image than other image src empty so why this.i think other input fields goes empty maybe that's why.Can i change only one image with-out changing to other.

Answer (score 0):

form page:

```
<form method="post" action="actionthingy.php">
    <input type="text" name="image1"/>
    <input type="text" name="image2"/>
    <input type="text" name="image3"/>
</form>
```

actionthingy.php:

```
<?php
echo '<img src="'.$_POST['image1'].'"/>';
echo '<img src="'.$_POST['image2'].'"/>';
echo '<img src="'.$_POST['image3'].'"/>';
?>
```