# Change one image into the multiple images.

Tags: php, html

I am using form inputs for change images i already done this.
Actually this images show on home page as a new titles.So i have URl input fields for changing images link.I am facing problem when i submit only one link then other one is empty so that's why other image src null.Basically i want to change which image this one old.
Is there any one know how to handle is issue.

**Html**

```
<form action="" method="post">

<input type="url" name="image1"/>

<input type="url" name="image2"/>

<input type="url" name="image3" />

<input type="submit"/>

</form>

<img src="<?php echo $img1; ?>" />

<img src="<?php echo $img2; ?>" />

<img src="<?php echo $img3; ?>" />
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

     $img1=$_POST['image1'];

     $img2=$_POST['image2'];

     $img3=$_POST['image3'];

?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand one bit of what you're trying to do. Could you try explaining it in more detail?

Comment: I want to make admin panel for update image src when i have.i have three images and i will give link with input filed's but problem is simple how to change only one image without disturbing other images src.

Comment: Change only one image where? What does this have to do with an admin panel? Why are you using `input` elements?

Comment: Didn't you already get an answer on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199914/update-image-src-with-input-field

Comment: I try to make panel there admin make changes in image src. Input filed's using for change link i have this idea but if you have batter idea please guide me i am new here.

Comment: I did it but now different problem.

Comment: You need to find the guy who helped you before because I can barely understand your use of the English language.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35396/discussion-between-affan-ahmad-and-devlshone)

Comment: Are trying to update image fields?

Comment: Yes Abraham of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="GET">
<input type="url" name="image1"/>
<input type="url" name="image2"/>
<input type="url" name="image3" />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>


<?php
echo '<img src="'.$_GET['image1'].'"/>';
echo '<img src="'.$_GET['image2'].'"/>';
echo '<img src="'.$_GET['image3'].'"/>';
?>
```